# Too frequent writes to Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a simple online game and need to write and check the card number in the Firebase Realtime database. This card can be changed by any player and it gets written to a database. There is a onDataChange listener which tracks the card number for every user. Usually it works well but sometimes these writes become to frequent (up to several hundreds per second) and they don't stop. In the app and in consolde I can see that card number is changing very very often and there is no way to stop it other than completely closing the app on all devices.
I was testing it with only 2 players. Usually the amount of writes shall not exceed 2-3 per second.
Can somebody give me a hint were to look for the cause?

```
roomRef = database.getReference(address);
    roomRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
 public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.exists() && snapshot.getValue()!= null){
                mainCardNumberInt = ((Long) snapshot.getValue()).intValue();
                if (mainCardNumberInt == 0) {
                    loadMainCard(mainCardNumberInt);
                } else {
                tvMainCardNumber.setText(getString(R.string.main_card_number) + mainCardNumberInt);
                loadMainCard(mainCardNumberInt);
                }
```

---

```
    private void loadMainCard(int randomNumber) {

    tvMainCardNumber.setText(getString(R.string.main_card_number) + randomNumber);
    loadPlayersCards(randomNumber);
    switch (randomNumber) {
        case 0:
            mainCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.card0);
            break;

        case 1:
            mainCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.card1);
            break;
       

        default:
            mainCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.card2);
           

    }

    roomRef.setValue(randomNumber);
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you attach the `onDataChange` to the database? I'm specifically interested in the path, and the way you attach the listener. Same for `roomRef`: can you show how that is initialized?

Comment: Please don't post code or additional information in comments. Instead click the `edit` link under your question to add it into your question.

Comment: Hi, @Frank van Puffelen. Have updated the code how I attached the listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attaching a permanent listener to `roomRef`, which:

1. Reads the current value and calls your `onDataChange` with it.
2. Continues to monitor the database, and if there's any updates to the data, it calls your `onDataChange` again with the updated value.

You then in `onDataChange` write a new value to the same `roomRef` location.

This results in an infinite loop, where the client is constantly getting the current value, writing an updates, then getting the updated value, writing another update, etc.

If you only want to get the value once, you can use `addListenerToSingleValueEvent`:

```
roomRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() { 
  @Override 
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot)
    ...
```

Now the `onDataChange` will only be called with the current value, and it won't monitor for updates.

Comment: Thank you, Frank. I will test it immidiatelly. Please also advise why it only happens sometimes, not always?

Comment: Hi @Frank van Puffelen. It looks like with this listener when I cannot receive an update when card number is changed by other user. I want all the users to see the same card number.

Comment: You're always calling `roomRef.setValue(randomNumber)` so the loop is always there in principle. You might be catching a lucky stream if the random number is the same as the current value, as in that case Firebase won't broadcast the value to the other listeners.

Comment: On your other comment: you should only call `roomRef.setValue(randomNumber)` when the user changes the card (so likely in an `onClick` handler or something like that), not whenever you happen to get a value from the database.

Comment: Thank you Frank. Your answer helped a lot. When I try to upvote it says the following : Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score